# nginx proxy_pass to phpmyadmin docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm running docker containers for nginx and phpmyadmin separately. I'm trying to proxy_pass nginx to phpmyadmin.

First I've tried this rule:

```
location ~ /admin-sql(/?)(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://phpmyadmin/$2;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;         
}
```

And it semi-works. I can access images and .js files just fine. The problem is that it doesn't seem to pass arguments to PHP scripts.

The URL below

```
example.com/admin-sql/js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts[]=jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange-1.3.js
```

Which is used to load a script in phpmyadmin's index.php fails with "Missing parameter".

I've tried this other rule, with PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI="http://example.com/admin-sql", but the results are the same:

```
location /admin-sql/ {
    proxy_pass http://phpmyadmin/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;         
}
```

It used to work without nginx, so it's definitely something about the rules.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, the 2nd solution works. What I had to change was the way I pass environment variables in docker-compose.

Passing them like that didn't work:

```
environment:
    PMA_HOST: mysql
    PMA_PORT: 3306
    PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI: "https://example.com/admin-sql/"
    PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
```

But it worked this way:

```
environment:
    - PMA_HOST=mysql
    - PMA_PORT=3306
    - PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI=https://example.com/admin-sql/
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```